# Powershell mail alert when multiple services are stopped on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to receive a single mail alert whenever multiple services are stopped from multiple servers. I made a mail function to call it in the loop if there are stopped services. The script I made works, but it send multiple mails for each stopped service as it is in the loop....

Any idea how I can compile all details in a single mail ?

```
#Clear values in variable in case report needs to be re-run to avoid duplicate info on the html report 
Clear-Variable -Name "Body"
Clear-Variable -Name "Body1" 
Clear-Variable -Name "serviceslist"
Clear-Variable -Name "service"
Clear-Variable -Name "machines"
Clear-Variable -Name "server"

Function SendMailFromPowershell () { 

Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server | Select MachineName, Name, DisplayName, Status, StartType | Sort-Object Name | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File -FilePath ".\report.html"


 $Body1 = "<br><h2>Please ensure all services are stopped before cleanup</h2><br>"
 $Body1 += Get-Content (".\report.html")
 
$Body = Out-String -InputObject $Body1 #( This basically converts the Sysytem.Object to System.String) 

$SMTPServer = "prodsmtp.ncc.local" 
$EmailFrom = "Daily_Report@ncc.local"  
$EmailTo = @('noc ncc <noc@ncc.com>')


$EmailSubject = "IISServices on $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")" 

Send-MailMessage  -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject  -Body $body -BodyAsHtml

} 


$machines = 'NPRODWEB01','NPRODWEB02'
$serviceslist = 'IISADMIN','w3logsvc','WinRM','W3SVC','WAS','NetPipeActivator','NetTcpActivator','vds','WcsPlugInService','THREADORDER'



$Header ="<head>
          <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
          <title>IIS Services</title>"
$Header += @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style></head>
"@


  foreach ($server in $machines) { 

    foreach ($service in $serviceslist) {

      
        if(Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server| Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}) {

        Write-Host "$service is Running $server" -ForegroundColor Cyan | Out-String 
        
        } 

        elseif (Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}) { 

        Write-Host "$service is stopped on $server" -ForegroundColor Green | Out-String 
        SendMailFromPowershell
        }

        else { 

        Write-Host "$service on $server error! Please manually check on server" -ForegroundColor Green | Out-String 

        }

    } 
    
}

#SendMailFromPowershell
```

Comment: For clarity.. Do you want to send an alert email if **[1]** one or some of the services are stopped (where they should be running), or **[2}** if some of the services are still running (where they should have been stopped)? Your code suggests option [1], but the body text in the email is about option [2] (_"Please ensure all services are stopped before cleanup"_)

Comment: Hi,
Yes, there's another bunch of code which i have not added to this thread, that's why there is the comment "Please ensure all services are stopped before cleanup"

What i want is to send a single mail alert containing one or more services which have not been stopped,  instead of receiving multiple mail alerts for every service which is stopped(to avoid too many mails)

The services are running on multiple servers(in a load balancer).

Comment: Hi Theo, Apologies for the delayed response.
Indeed this is just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot again for the help. This will help me in the future for writing other scripts as well : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for explaining you need to send an email with services that are still running.
Leaving most of your function body intact, I would do it like this:

```
# changed the function name to comply with the PowerShell Verb-Noun naming convention
function Send-MailFromPowershell { 
    $machines     = 'NPRODWEB01','NPRODWEB02'
    $serviceslist = 'IISADMIN','w3logsvc','WinRM','W3SVC','WAS','NetPipeActivator','NetTcpActivator','vds','WcsPlugInService','THREADORDER'
    # loop over the servers 
    $result = foreach ($server in $machines) { 
        # loop over the services in the list
        foreach ($service in $serviceslist) {
            try {
                # try and get this service, jump to the catch block if something goes wrong
                $svc = Get-Service -Name $service  -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop
                if ($svc.Status -eq 'Running') {
                    Write-Warning "Service '$service' is still Running on $server"
                    # output an object to be collected in $result
                    $svc | Select-Object MachineName, Name, DisplayName, Status, StartType
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "$service is stopped on $server" -ForegroundColor Green
                }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "$server error! Please manually check on server`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
            }
        }
    }

    # only send an email if there is something to alert (not all services were stopped)
    # the @() is needed to force $result to be an array even if it has only one item
    if (@($result).Count) {
        # convert the resulting array of objects into a HTML table
        $table = ($result | Sort-Object MachineName, Name | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -join [environment]::NewLine

        # create a HTML template for the email using a Here-String
        $htmlTemplate = @'
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
    <title>IIS Services</title>"
    <style>
        TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
        TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
        TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Please ensure all services are stopped before cleanup</h2>
<br />
@@TABLE@@
</body></html>
'@

        # create a Hashtable to splat the parameters to Send-MailMessage
        $mailParams = @{
            From       = 'Daily_Report@ncc.local'
            To         = 'noc ncc <noc@ncc.com>'
            Subject    = 'IISServices on {0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date)
            SmtpServer = 'prodsmtp.ncc.local'
            Body       = $htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLE@@', $table
            BodyAsHtml = $true
        }

        # send the email
        Send-MailMessage @mailParams
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "All services were stopped. No email was sent." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}

# call the function
Send-MailFromPowershell
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, that makes sense.
Would it be possible to use the "exit()" command after the mail has been sent ? The goal is to prevent the script from running the rest of the commands(not included in this thread) 
If I use it in the loop, that would prevent the script from looping through all the services to check their status if am correct?

Or i believe i can just use it after calling the function "Send-MailFromPowershell"

Comment: @TitanL0rd You could do `exit` in the function, as the last command just above the final closing bracket `}`, or if you prefer, directly after calling the function. Both places will stop the script after sending the email.